# PHP - An if statement with concatenated '&&' and '||' can give problems?

Tags: php, if-statement, operators

I have a problem with a form check that use an if statement with multiple 'and' and 'or' operators. This check return me an anomalous occasionally false value.

```
public function insert_checkForm($form) {
    $form = array_filter($form);
    if (
        !isset($form['report_id']) ||
        !isset($form['date']) ||
        !isset($form['technical_id']) ||
        isset($form['travel_go_from']) != isset($form['travel_go_to']) ||
        isset($form['work_go_from']) != isset($form['work_go_to']) ||
        !isset($form['travel_go_from']) && 
        !isset($form['travel_go_to']) && 
        !isset($form['work_go_from']) && 
        !isset($form['work_go_to'])
    ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return $form;
    }
}
```

Last question, the above code changes compared to this (in spite of the priorities of and operators)?

```
[...]
!isset($form['report_id']) ||
!isset($form['date']) ||
!isset($form['technical_id']) ||
(isset($form['travel_go_from']) != isset($form['travel_go_to'])) ||
(isset($form['work_go_from']) != isset($form['work_go_to'])) ||
(!isset($form['travel_go_from']) && !isset($form['travel_go_to']) && !isset($form['work_go_from']) && !isset($form['work_go_to']))
[...]
```

Thanks =)

Comment: Did you do math in school? If yes, the grouping based on parenthesis work in the same way.

Comment: Use more brackets(parenthesis) to make it more obvious what you would like. I also suggest that this may not be the best if structure and there are likely better ways to go about this.

Comment: Also I agree 100% with ^. Your code makes it really hard to see what is going on and makes it extremely easy to miss something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common problem with [isset()](http://php.net/isset) is that it returns false when the item is NOT SET but also returns false if the item **IS SET && IS NULL**.

```
isset($arr['nonexisting']); //this returns: false
$arr['existing'] = null;
isset($arr['existing']); //this returns: false
```